# Can decisions be wise?

Tags: vocabulary, english-to-latin-translation, word-choice

I was asked recently how to translate "a wise decision" (as either the act of deciding, or the result) into Latin. "Wisdom" could perhaps be the Greek loanword *sophia* or the native Latin *sapientia*; a decision might be a *consilium* or an *arbitrium*. But can a *consilium* actually be *sapiens* or have *sapientia*? How do I indicate that the decision was made wisely/by a wise person, rather than that the *consilium* itself *sapit*?

Comment: Latin and Greek (even English) poetry and even prose will quite often employ [transferred epithets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypallage).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Consilium sapiens** is attested by Ovid ([Met. 13](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0029%3Abook%3D13%3Acard%3D399).433):

> ...Polymestoris illic
>   regia dives erat, cui te commisit alendum
>   clam, Polydore, pater Phrygiisque removit ab armis,
>   **consilium sapiens**, sceleris nisi praemia magnas
>   adiecisset opes, animi inritamen avari

*(Thanks brianpck for pointing out my mistake in a previous example, and offering this one as an alternative)*

A later example is attested in XX century Ecclesiastical Latin by St. John XXIII  ([Humanae Salutis](https://w2.vatican.va/content/john-xxiii/la/apost_constitutions/1961/documents/hf_j-xxiii_apc_19611225_humanae-salutis.html), 14):

> Priusquam argumenta in Concilio pertractanda statueremus, ante omnia *prudens* et **sapiens** rogavimus **consilium** Patres Cardinales, universi catholici orbis Episcopos, ...

(I also underline *prudens* for what it's worth.)

---

In a side comment, the Vulgate (post-classical) has an example of *sapienter respondere* ([Mc 12](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.02.0060:book=Mark:chapter=12&highlight=sapienter), 34), which may serve as an argument for *sapiens responsum* (although not exactly a decision, another example of an action by a man considered itself wise, or, as pointed out in the comments, a transferred epithet):

> Iesus autem videns quod **sapienter** **respondisset** dixit illi non es longe a regno Dei